# Adverbs in the middle of phrasal verbs: He got quickly dressed

Tags: adverbs, structure

I did an activity with my students regarding adverb position. This is the prompt:
He got dressed (quickly).

The answers I provided were:

- He got dressed **quickly**.
- He **quickly** got dressed.

However, a student came up with:

- He got **quickly** dressed.

Is that option feasible? It doesn't sound right to me. Can that kind of adverb get in the middle of the phrasal verb?

Comment: He got *right* up is okay, but this positon for *quickly* is off.

Comment: "phrasal verb" is often a fuzzy classification. To the extent that we "define" a usage as a phrasal verb, it *can't* be interrupted by an adverbial element. But there are lots of written instances of [***get smartly dressed***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+smartly+dressed%22), for example. So far as I'm concerned, *in those specific contexts*, the words "get dressed" simply aren't being used as a true phrasal verb. Which arguably makes those linked examples *just slightly* "marked", but not really enough for the average reader to notice.

Comment: ...you can't possibly ***run slowly up** a tab in a wine bar*, for example, because there's absolutely no way for ***run up*** to have a "non-phrasal verb" sense in that context.

Comment: To "get smartly dressed" is to go from a state of not being smartly dressed to a state of being smartly dressed. But there is no such thing as a state of being *quickly dressed*, as "quickly" describes the change, not the state.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is wrong - it's still clearly understandable and it does make sense. However it's quite unusual to add "quickly" in the middle of "get dressed".  A quick google ngram search reveals this much. You could say it's not particularly idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

> *He got quickly dressed.*

There is no so-called phrasal verb here.

It simply means "He became quickly dressed", where "dressed" is an adjective relating to "he".

The linear position of "quickly" is open to criticism, with most speakers preferring it in pre-verbal position: *He quickly got dressed*, or in post-verbal position: *He got dressed quickly*.

Answer (score 0):

Until not all that long ago it was considered an error, incorrect and wrong. Then Star Trek happened, with its catchphrase of *To boldly go where no man has gone before*, and linguists humorously called it *To boldly split infinitives where no infinitive has been split before*.

While "incorrect", this form obviously sounded more impactful than the "correct" *To go boldly where...* - and spearheaded a broader change in language: split infinitives entered mainstream use, and had to be accepted as a valid, correct technique. After that adverbs were inserted into all kinds of places in sentence, including splitting phrasal verbs, fossilized phrases, modal verb phrases, phrasal verb phrases and more, and in general while commonly considered poor style, they are nowadays widely accepted as correct English.

ps. *get dressed* isn't a phrasal verb - in this context *get* is used as a normal verb, similar to *become*. *Get* can be a phrasal verb, like in *get along with...* but not here. *Get dressed* is just an idiomatic, somewhat fossilized phrase - but that's moot regarding the problem as neither phrasal verbs nor fossilized phrases are nowadays safe from adverb insertion.